# Does .NET Embedding work on Visual Studio on Windows or only VS on mac?

Tags: xamarin.ios, embeddinator

I have an Xamarin ios class library that I want to .Net Embedding to 'embed' for use by an Xcode Objective-C app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/dotnet-embedding/get-started/objective-c/#requirements)

**Requirements**

> To use .NET Embedding with Objective-C, you'll need a Mac running:
>
> ```
> macOS 10.12 (Sierra) or later
> Xcode 8.3.2 or later
> Mono 5.0
> ```
>
> You can install Visual Studio for Mac to edit and compile your C#
>   code.

**Note**

> Earlier versions of macOS, Xcode, and Mono might work, but are
>   untested and unsupported
>       Code generation can be done on Windows, but it is only possible to compile it on a Mac computer where Xcode is installed

Comment: That didn't answer the question I had in mind.  I will clarify and rephrase it:  Does .NET Embedding work on Visual Studio on Windows or only VS on mac?  I would prefer on Windows, since that where the rest of the product code is.

Comment: The consensus I see online is that remote control by Visual Studio on Windows of MacOS  to do .Net Embedding doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, embeddinator 4000 works in Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2019.

I have generated .aar for Android + Java.
However, there are many limitations of the generated aar.
e.g. functions that use non-primitive types get ignored and you do not have those in generated aar etc.